# Запись MJPEG потока

Tags: ffmpeg, видео

подскажите, товарищщи, есть у меня MJPEG поток.

сейчас я его пишу ffmpeg`ом 3 к/с, но так я кушаю большой поток, который мне не нужен

мне по-хорошему надо хватать всего 1 кадр в минуту.

Кто-нить сталкивался с такими задачами? 
Придётся писать приблуду или можно коммандной строкой ffmpeg`а обойтись?

Comment: Посмотрите параметр `-r`, вдруг то, что нужно.

Comment: к сожалению, его не хватает...

Answer (score 2):

`-r` в данном случае нужно ставить перед `-i` как параметр входного потока. Кадры не удовлетворяющие этому будут проигнорированы.